# Python2 - Summing "for" loop output

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, for-loop

I'm trying to make a script that takes a balances of multiple addresses from a json file and adds them together to make a final balance.

This is the code so far -

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('hd-wallet-addrs/addresses.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)

for balance in data:
    print balance['balance']
```

**This is what's in the json file:**

```
[
    {
        "addr": "1ERDMDducUsmrajDpQjoKxAHCqbTMEU9R6",
        "balance": "21.00000000"
    },
    {
        "addr": "1DvmasdbaFD7Tj6diu6D8WVc1Bkbj7jYRM",
        "balance": "0.30000000"
    },
    {
        "addr": "18xkkUi7qagUuBAg572UsmDKcZTP5zxaDB",
        "balance": "0.80000000"
    },
    {
        "addr": "1MmTDCsySdsWRVbNFwXBy2APW5kGsynkaA3",
        "balance": "0.005"
    },

]
```

The output is like this:

```
21
0.3
0.8
0.005
```

How should I edit my code to add the numbers together?

Comment: I didn't. I used DeepSpace's.

Comment: I tend to not be swayed by time. I prefer code readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually add them together...

```
total = 0
for balance in data:
    total += float(balance['balance'])
print total
```

Or using `sum`:

```
print sum(float(temp_balance['balance']) for temp_balance in data)
```

Comment: Second one worked! Thanks for the help. First one gave me "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'unicode'"

Answer (score 1):

Most pythonic way to achieve this will be:

```
final_balance = sum(map(float, [balance['balance'] for balance in data]))
```

[map()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) will convert the list of `str` numbers to `float` numbers, and [sum()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) will add them together.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sum` function and list comprehension:

```
sum([float(b['balance']) for b in balance])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
balance_prev = 0
balance_sum = 0
for balance in data:
    balance_sum = float(balance_prev) + float(balance['balance'])
    balance_prev = balance_sum
print balance['balance']
```

hope this help!!